# How to get all cities of a country in dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dropdown, cities-skylines-api

Is there any package or api from where i get all cities of country in my case (Pakistan)?

Comment: For that you need to store that data locally in app or have database and create API.

Answer (score 0):

It gives the **country_state_city_picker** package:
https://pub.dev/packages/country_state_city_picker

With this package you can choose a state and become there cities, but I don't know how much and what for cities you become for Pakistan. You must try it for your specific country (Pakistan).